# Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

I have Windows Server 2019 Standard and I can update but I can not add a PIN it is alwayes disabled and there is the red message read: "Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization"

I tried "turn on convience PIN sign-in" in group policy and I restart the server but the PIN still disabled and the red message still there. Any solution to this ?

Edit:
Admin account does not work I need to login with domain account ? I dont have domain account login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running a Server OS then you should be using a domain account and the server should be setup properly.

That being said, you can use the `gpresult /R` command to output the group policies that are applied to the command line, or you can use `gpresult /H results.html` to output the policies to an HTML file.